# can django authentication be combined with django rest framework basic auth?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Good day, I have the following question.
I'm still learning and improving my django level, but I'm a bite confused with a project that I'm working on.

For a django web app, which requires a user to register with their email and password, I used the custom user and backend as shown the djangoproject website.

However, later on I realised that  the app will have to make some api call with basic auth, which I assumes will be the registered user email and password.

My questions is the following:
 -  does it really make sense two have those two authentications? because I'm thinking to remove the django one, and rather use the django_rest_framework auth.

Any advise will be helpful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great thing about DRF is that it supports multiple authentication schemes. By default it uses session + basic auth (exactly what you need).

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
),
```

where `SessionAuthentication` is reusing the standard django auth flow (username/pass) + support basic auth.

Comment: so will you drop the django authentication in favor of the rest framework one